# if condition which executes only on weekdays, i.e. mon-fri

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to have a condition, which executes only on weekdays, 
the variable @Executedate is int type and take only the day part of the datetime,if @Executeday is a saturday or sunday, it should be reset to monday.

Here is the piece of code,

```
Declare @Executeday int      

declare @time varchar(200)

set @time =  convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 108)

if day(getdate()) < 16                          
begin 

set @Executeday = (select top 1 Description from cts_configuration(nolock) where name like 'ReminderMailerFirstFortNightDay')

end
else                          
begin         
set @Executeday = (select top 1 Description from cts_configuration(nolock) where name like 'ReminderMailerSecondFortNightDay')

 end

if (day(getdate())=@Executeday) or (day(getdate())=@Executeday+2) or (day(getdate())=@Executeday+4)

begin

if(@time between '10:00:00' and '11:00:00') 
begin
```

I want the if condition here...(That resets @executeday to Monday, if it is a sat or sun)

Comment: What is "day part", "monday" or "21st"? Did you already try anything?

Comment: Here is the code. It will execute 3 times a week, on alternate days, if any day falls on a saturday or sunday, @Executeday shud be reset to  monday of the next week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ExecuteDay AS int = 7;

DECLARE @Today AS date = GETDATE();
DECLARE @ExecuteDate AS date = DATEADD(day, @ExecuteDay - DATEPART(day, @Today), @Today);
DECLARE @WeekDay AS int = (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @ExecuteDate)) % 7;

IF @WeekDay IN (0, 1)
    SET @ExecuteDate = DATEADD(day, 2 - @WeekDay, @ExecuteDate)

PRINT @ExecuteDate
```